# How to sum up N array elements, to the left of the given element?

Tags: java, arrays, sequence

Sorry if the question is confusing, I am new to programming and I didn't know how to formulate it, and even Google couldn't understand me number of times.

I am trying to solve some kind of Fibonnaci sequence, but instead of summing the last 2 numbers, it should sum up the last N numbers.

```
public double[] sequenceSum(double[] sequence) {
//some fancy method here
}
```

Where the sequence.length is actually how much numbers you should sum up.
So if the call is:
seqeunceSum(1,2,3,4);

...the sequence should continue {1,2,3,4,10,18,35,67...}.

if the call is:
seqeunceSum(1,0,1,0,1);
...the sequence should continue {1,0,1,0,1,3,5,10,19,38....}.

The sequence has its limits, of course, otherwise it'd be infinite, but I only need help with **how to sum up N number of array elements, to the left**

Thanks a lot,

> EDIT:

Thanks, I took few opinions from here and I solved it.

And yes, the sequence has limits, sorry for not including that in the parameters, I judged on previous advise to ask Minimal and Specific questions.

Here is my code:

```
public double[] sequenceSum(double[] sequence, int n) {
      double[] xArray = Arrays.copyOf(sequence, n);
      for(int i = sequence.length; i<n; i++){
      double sum = 0;
         for (int j=(i-sequence.length); j < i; j++) {
            sum += xArray[j];
            }
         xArray[i] = sum;
      }
      return xArray;
  }
}
```

Thanks everyone,

Comment: Have you tried something? This seems more than do-able. `array.length` and recursion should help you.

Comment: I have total of 2 months Java experience, and Java is my first language :)

I've searched the libraries but it's too complex for now. Lots of methods I don't understand

Comment: I will see what recursion does right away. Thanks. In fact, I'd like to solve it on my own, I just want to know where to look in the APIs

Comment: What's going to stop your sequenceSum method from summing?  You can't return an infinite sequence.

Comment: Your explanation samples doesn't make any sense without a proper definition of your function. Your function should receive the original sequence AND the N characters to sum ALSO the condition for when it should stop. For the samples you gave, `1,0,1,0,1` summing all next is `3` but why the next is `5`? See why you need to define mentioned parameters?

Comment: @JorgeCampos it sums up the last 'sequence.length' numbers.
So because 1,0,1,0,1 has 5 elements, all of the next elements will be the sum of the last 5 elements in the array.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I mentioned that it has limits, but in my last questions asked on StackOverflow I was advised to ask as specific as possible question.

Comment: I understand that, but you didn't account for the new element you added (3) so your sequence.lenght will by 6 now, right? So either I am right or you forgot to mention that the sequence.lenght should stick with the original lenght

Comment: Yea I forgot to mention that sorry @JorgeCampos 
Anyway, I solved it.

Comment: @YassinHajaj Thanks a lot, your guidance helped me the most, I Googled what recursion was. To be honest, I thought it's some method from the Java libraries because English is not my native :))

Comment: @Kokolo You're welcome :) As long as you've learned something new today, it's the most important :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A best practice is to keep same functionality that could be reused in a own/separate function, so you can use this anywhere else in your programm.
(Also it makes your code more structured and readable)

So add the following function to your code:

```
public double sumAll(double[] numbers) {
    double result = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numbers.length; i++){
        result += numbers[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

And than you can call it inside your sequenceSum function like:

```
double sum = sumAll(sequence);
// Your code to create the next sequence elements...
```

Another hint: If you just use this function for the Fibbonaci sequence and similar integer problems use the data type int, because floating point numbers (in this case double) add up floating point "noise". (You find informations about this problem [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/))

Comment: Thanks, this is very close to the answer, and it gave me nice heads up.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should sum integers rather than doubles.  You can convert the integers to doubles if necessary.

Second, you need to include a stop condition.  I suggest a total length.  This would make the method signature:

```
public int[] sequenceSum(int[] sequence, int length)
```

Rather than give you code, I'll just give you the steps you need to write the code:

1. Create the int output array of length length.
2. Get the sequence length.
3. Copy the sequence array to the output array.
4. Sum the sequence values, from index 0 to index sequence length - 1, and add the sum to the output array.
5. Repeat step 4, adding 1 to the start index and adding 1 to the end index, until the output array is full.